# JQuery Validation conditional validation not working on conditional requirement

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am trying to make a `select` required only if another `select` element has "Tables" selected.

Here is the select that I'm trying to validate:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" id="table_location" name="table_location">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Oracle">Oracle</option>
      </select>
```

This is the `select` that I'm using to check if the above element is required or not:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" id="data_source" >
              <option value="Tables">Table(s)</option>
              <option value="Files">File(s)</option>
              <option value="Both">Tables and Files</option>
          </select>
```

This is the rule I'm trying to use to validate:

```
 table_location: {
        required: function(element) {
            return $("#data_source").val()=="Tables";
        }
    },
```

Currently for conditional requirements, I'm having to add the rules in another JavaScript file where I'm writing the bulk of my code and this is getting messy. I have confirmed that the form name is correct and the elements are inside of it. Any static requirements work, but most of the conditional ones don't, this is just one example. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `$("#data_source").find("option:selected").val();`

Comment: @Sinto I tried that and in the console `$("#data_source").find("option:selected").val()=="Tables"` returns true, but it still lets me pass the page with the selected object being blank.